# How to deploy multiple contracts in one chaincode(Hyperledger fabric)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I used `fabric-contractapi-go` to write my chaincode, and this chaincode contains two contracts. I have tested it in the fabric-chaincodedev-mode. But when I deploy it in the fabric-firstnetwork using such commands, I can't get the second contract no matter in the command line nor fabric-gateway-sdk-java.

```
#package
docker exec cli peer lifecycle chaincode package helloworld.tar.gz \
--path github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/helloworld/go/ \
--label helloworld_1

#install in two orgs
docker exec cli peer lifecycle chaincode install helloworld.tar.gz
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
  cli peer lifecycle chaincode install helloworld.tar.gz 

#approve in tow orgs
docker exec cli peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg \
  --tls \
  --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem \
  --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1 \
  --init-required --sequence 1 --waitForEvent --package-id ${PACKAGE_ID}

docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
  cli peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg \
  --tls \
  --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem \
  --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1 --init-required \
  --sequence 1 --waitForEvent --package-id ${PACKAGE_ID}

#commit
docker exec cli peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
  --tls \
  --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem \
  --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
  --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
  --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
  --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
  --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1 --sequence 1 --init-required
```

Comment: Let me know if you figured this out!

Answer (score 0):

In your chaincode

```
func main () {
  contracts := []contractapi.ContractInterface{&contract.A{}, &contract.B{}}
  yourChaincode, _ := contractapi.NewChaincode(contracts...)
  if err := yourChaincode.Start();err!=nil{
    log.Panicf("Error starting chaincode: %v",err) 
  }
}
```

In your application you can use it as

```
contractA := network.GetContractWithName("yourChaincodeName","contractA")
contractB := network.GetContractWithName("yourChaincodeName","contractB")
```

"yourChaincodeName" is the name you've used to deploy the Chaincode in your channel